# How do you change responsive font size breakpoints in Material-ui theme? (h1, h2, h3, ...)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsiveness

Is there a way to only change the values of Typography elements at the default breakpoints, or do you just have to override them as if you were to set them explicitly? The documentation doesn't really delve into *how* to deviate from the default sizes in `responsiveFontSizes`. Is there a best-practice/standard way of doing it that I'm not aware of?

I'm not even sure of how to change the values per breakpoint (by looking at the docs here): https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/?expand-path=$.typography